How to remove few fields in grid using javascript in ext.js
Below is my javascript code that I am using to remove few columns in grid
data: function (){
var data = this.base.data.call(this);
data[0].lookup.gridcustomization.gridSequence= data[0].lookup.gridcustomization.gridSequence.filter(
item => item.dataIndex != "st1" && item.dataIndex !==  "ZonalCode"
);
return data;
}

The above code removes the 2 records in gridcustomization but it is still getting binded in frontend. Will the data in formHtml and quicktip makes the data still to be displayed in frontend if yes how can I remove those two from my quicktip and formTitle i finally should not see ST1 and ZonalCode in grid


Could you setup a fiddle? this would help to understand what you need, and why data-binding is still active. Typically you might want to remove the data from the store store.removeRecord(record) and it will update your data-binding too. Please setup a fiddle.
